# How to remove a WPF window from a C# project

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a WPF C# application in Visual Studio. In this application, I created a new WPF window. I decided to move that window into it's own project, and have deleted the window from current project (deleted the XAML and code behind) But the original project keeps giving me an error, saying it cannot find the XAML (of the deleted window).

I have searched every file in the project to find where there is a reference to the deleted XAML file, but I cannot. So, what file is this reference?

Comment: sometimes enough is clear and rebuild project.

Comment: Maybe in App.xaml. It would be helpful if you add a snippet of your project files structure

Comment: @SilnyToJa or just create an empty (nearly empty) XAML/code behind file with the name of missing file. But, yeah, probably going to recreate project.

Comment: Well, this is awkward. Today when at work, and restarting Visual Studio and reloading the project, it is now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems all I had to do was reload the project. When I got back to work the following day, and reloaded Visual Studio, and the project, it is now working.